# Laravel 5.4 (1/1) FatalErrorException - Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in CssSelectot\rConverter.php line 34

Tags: laravel

Can anyone please help me with the above error. I am running Laravel 5.4 and php 5.6. I can register a user and be able to login but whenever I attempt to send an email(password recovery email and email verification for example) I get the above error. [image]

Comment: post your code this is not giving any usefull information

Comment: When I register a user I get the above error but when I check on users table a user is created successfully. I believe error comes when my application is trying to send an email.

Comment: Error Log:  [11-May-2018 07:44:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL  /public_html/msc/vendor/symfony/css-selector/CssSelectorConverter.php on line 34

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
composer --prefer-dist --verbose -vvv update
```

Comment: Can you provide some context about this? If a running script throws an error, how can composer solve this?

Comment: This script will download the compatible packages based on your php version. It will uninstall and install the right packages for you.

Comment: Why do you think that anything is not compatible?

Comment: Based on my experience I run the composer to PHP 7 then afterwards, we uploaded in PHP5.6.36. Then we encounter this issue. I decided to debug and trace the issue, and I found out and solved it by using the given script. The symfony/css-selector is maybe 4 and up and not compatible to his PHP Version. From 4 to 3.4-dev.